# Animate package problem with Ghostscript version

Tags: beamer, miktex, animate, ghostscript

I am using  the animate package to make an animation in my beamer presentation.

While compiling I use Latex -> dvi2ps -> ps2pdf
When I do ps2pdf there is an error telling me that my Ghostscript version is too old and that animations won't work unless I download the Ghostscript 9.15 version, which I have done and installed...

Still, it always shows me the same error and when I open my Pdf file there is any animation. However, if I open de ps file I can see that it read the animation code.

Do you have any idea of how I can solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Ana

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: A possible fix is given here:

[How to configure WinEdt/MikTeX/ps2pdf to use a new version of Ghostscript when converting ps->pdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214616)

---

Somehow, the old ghostscript installation is found first while invoking `ps2pdf`, most likely due to your `PATH` settings. If you are on Windows, you should update to TeXLive-2014 and uninstall any standalone Ghostscript on your computer. TeXLive-2014 for Windows with updated packages has its own Ghostscript-9.15 installation.

You can get the path to the `ps2pdf` executable that is actually run by typing

```
where ps2pdf
```

at the DOS command prompt (Start -> Run -> `cmd.exe`).

Comment: Thank you AlexG. I have checked the PATH and it is pointing in the right direction towards Ghostscript 9.15. I did not find any older version of Ghostcript in my computer. I tried to install TeXLive 2014 (I did not know about it) and the installation did not finished (after more than 1h installing...). I think this is because I am on Windows 7 64bit and there is any version of TeXLive2014 for 64bit(?).

Comment: @AnaGaspar So you are using MiKTeX. It ships with Ghostscript too, but that was packaged more than two years ago (5/30/2012). Try to uninstall it from within the MiKTeX package manager or ask the MiKTeX maintainer to update it.

Comment: @AnaGaspar Run `where ps2pdf` at the DOS command prompt. It tells you which Ghostscript is being executed.