# png figures in latex

Tags: miktex, conversion, png

I have been struggling for a while trying to insert png figures. I want to use powerdot so I should go through latex->dvi->ps->pdf.

The following did work until my last update

```
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,bb=0 0 401 337]{DipoloSmoot.png}
```

No errors in LaTeX - dvips but in the ps2pdf step

I am using a MikTeX installation on Windows 10:

```
>>> pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
(preloaded format=latex 2016.8.6)
>>> dvips.exe -Ppdf "test_powerdot_png.dvi"
This is dvips(k) 5.996 Copyright 2016 Radical Eye Software
(www.radicaleye.com) *' TeX output 2016.08.06:1831' -> test_powerdot_png.ps

>>> "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE
-dBATCH -sOutputFile="test_powerdot_png.pdf" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c
-setpdfwrite -f "test_powerdot_png.ps"
...
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Please forgive my inexperience, I don't know how to upload log and relevant files.
Any hint? Thank you in advance

Surfing around I see things similar to mine:

[How to configure WinEdt/MikTeX/ps2pdf to use a new version of Ghostscript when converting ps->pdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214616/how-to-configure-winedt-miktex-ps2pdf-to-use-a-new-version-of-ghostscript-when-c)
which seems to be solved in the current MikTeX distribution.

However none of the solutions solves the problem.

Comment: `dvips` tries to use `emtex special` for bitmap images.
But I think that is not always successful. It is better to
convert bitmap images to eps files before the latex:
for example, `magick DipoloSmoot.png DipoloSmoot.eps`

`\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{DipoloSmoot.eps}`

Comment: But the message `No such file or directory` may
suggest other problem in your case.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto: good to learn that dvips calls some other piece of tex, thanks. I will investigate in that direction. If the ps from bitmap is produced on the flight and it doesn't work, that may explain the `No such file or directory` .

Comment: I realized looking at the `.dvi` file that the `.png` was not converted anymore to `.eps`.  I obtained the previous behaviour by including `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.png}{eps}{.bb}{``convert #1 eps:-}` after having installed [ImageMagick®](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

Comment: Was the conversion once made by the MikTeK environment? Has the default behaviour changed?

Comment: I don't know about MikTeX. Did you add an option -shell-escape
(or -enable-write18 ?) ?
Anyway, `convert DipoloSmoot.png DipoloSmoot.eps` before
running latex must be OK without touching the `\DeclareGraphicsRule`.

Comment: If you use the `convert` command, be sure that
there is the image magick binary directory before the
`c:\windows\system32` in the `PATH`. The `magick` command
in the recent image magick may be safer than the `convert`
command.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto: indeed converting .png to .eps before works. Also the `\DeclareGraphicsRule` works,  setting the option `-R0` in `dvips.exe`. Thank you for flagging the issue about convert, I checked it uses ImageMagick. With your suggestions this problem has been solved. I am still wondering how and why the behaviour changed but this is irrelevant now!

Comment: Still not happy with the conversion, as the size in pixels of the `.eps` filsize was different from the original `.png` one, I found necessary to give the option `-density 72x72 -units PixelsPerInch` to the `convert` command:      `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.png}{eps}{.bb}{\`convert #1 -density 72x72 -units PixelsPerInch eps:-}` . Typo corrected: single backtick before `convert`.

Answer (score 1):

After having installed [ImageMagick®](http://www.imagemagick.org):

- either convert images beforehand, as indicated by Akira KaKuto:

  ```
  > convert DipoloSmoot.png DipoloSmoot.eps
  ```

before running latex.

- or insert in your tex file:

  ```
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{.png}{eps}{.bb}
  {`convert #1 -density 72x72 -units PixelsPerInch eps:-}
  ```

Depending on which program created the .png file, you may need to use the convert option -density 72x72 -units PixelsPerInch, in both cases.